# RequireNativeComponent: "ToolbarAndroid" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I followed the steps of the installation [tutorial toolbarAndoid](https://github.com/react-native-community/toolbar-android) and the implementation [tutorial expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/toolbarandroid/), but when running on the android application the following stack appears:

```
InvariantViolation: requireNativeComponent: "ToolbarAndroid" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
   in ToolbarAndroid (at ToobarAndroid.android.js:228)
   in ToolbarAndroid (at ToobarAndroid.android.js:242)
   in FowardRef (at Main.js:9)
   in Main (created by SceneView)
   in SceneView (created by Drawer)
   in RCTView (created by ResourceSavingScene)
   ...
```

I'm using:

- Expo 37.0.3 (SDK37)
- React Native: 0.61.4
- React Navigation: 4.3.9
- App Expo Client version: 2.15.4